# SQL select in select where get from result max

Tags: mysql

I have a table named **works** with column names: **group_id, name, money**

[image]

My query select group_id and sum money like this:

```
select group_id, sum(money) as time FROM works group by group_id
```

This query yields the following results

[image]

Now I need to supplement the query to find the max money and group id. I want to get the following result:

```
group id: 2, money: 320
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select g.group_name, sum(money) as time
from works w
INNER JOIN group g on g.group_id = w.group_id
group by w.group_id
order by sum(money) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Post the structure of the table group

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just order by money and choose the first row:

```
select group_id, sum(money) as time
from works
group by group_id
order by sum(money) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: return group_id: 2, money: 320. I have another table `Groups` his have two columns: `id` and `name`, group_id column value it's from table `Groups` id column value. How i can now return instead of group id: 2 write name.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select group_id, sum(money) as money as time FROM works group by group_id having max(money)
```